# Jquery how can i count the index number from parent?

Tags: jquery

i have a this function to count the index number, but i need to count it from it's parents parent, so my result of index would be 0,1,2.

how can i do this?

myfuntion://

​html:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="child1">
        <h3>title one</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="child1">
        <h3>title one</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="child1">
        <h3>title one</h3>
    </div>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Jquery:

```
​$('h3','#parent')​​​​​​​​​.click(function(){
    alert($(this).index('#parent'))            
})​
```

Comment: do you want the index of the `.child1` div containing the `h3`?

Comment: yes, i need the result of 0,1,2 while clicking appropriate h3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change your function with

```
var h3p = $('h3','#parent');
h3p.click(function(){
    alert(h3p.index($(this)));           
});
```

example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HwySz/

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/index/):

> If .index() is called on a collection of elements and a DOM element or jQuery object is passed in, .index() returns an integer indicating the position of the passed element relative to the original collection.

With that in mind, you want this:

```
var $h3s = ​$('#parent h3')​​​​​​​​​
$h3s.click(function(){
    alert($h3s.index($(this)));        
})​;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZcBBY/

I've removed the eventListener for #parent and binded it only on h3. Finding the index of the containing div is done with `$(this).parent().index()`

Entire block:

```
$('h3').click(function(){
    alert($(this).parent().index())            
})​
```

Comment: in case, if there is no parent then?